# Basic javascript flow - in various browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to learn the flow in JavaScript with a very simple JavaScript example but three  browsers (Chrome, IE and Firefox) all three are showing different flow patterns and different end results. I know there are cross-browser issues that are to be expected, but this one is super simple. So I am trying to understand how to interpret how JavaScript actually flows.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test 01</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.bgColor = "red"; 
    </script>

</head>

<body bgColor="yellow">

<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script>alert("after para 1");</script>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<script>alert("after para 2");</script>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<script>alert("after para 3");</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am seeing is that the "Paragraph 1" text is showing up in Chrome after the alert and so on with the other two alerts also. IE and Firefox seem to be doing the right thing here - showing the text before the alert.

And between IE and Firefox, IE is ending up with a red background and Firefox with yellow. So not sure exactly what to interpret.. behavior is different for all the browsers.

How do you learn about how this is exactly supposed to work?

Edit: removing the var x=10 that is not relevant for this question. And the question is how do you interpret chromes behavior where the alert is showing up before the relevant text - as well as why the bgcolor is being overridden in one case whereas not in others.

Comment: You have a rouge `var x= 10;` that isn't in the script tags.

Comment: What's the question here? If it's really "how do you learn about..." then this is off-topic.

Comment: (Possibly) **Related**: [BlockingJS](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS).

Comment: Let's not touch `bgColor`, shan't we?

Comment: @JanDvorak nope, best if we don't...

Comment: Don't focus on this, because writing scripts that interact with the user or with the DOM while the DOM is not ready is in most cases a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Let's also say it's a bad idea to assume the browser will repaint just before showing an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to learn the flow in JavaScript with a very simple
>   JavaScript example but three browsers (Chrome, IE and Firefox) all
>   three are showing different flow patterns and different end results.

What you are talking about is the [HTML engine in different browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine). So this is about processing HTML rather than processing javascript...

> How do you learn about how this is exactly supposed to work?

That depends on... I like to create single page javascript applications, which don't load much HTML before the window.onload (or DOMContentLoaded) event fires. So I start with an empty body and build the page completely with javascript. By some of the project you need graceful degradation and you start with a HTML implementing some basic features and you can add javascript to implement more advanced features. By this scenario you need to wait the previously mentioned events if your code wants to do anything with DOM. Otherwise there is no guarantee about which order the browser will render DOM elements and execute javascript commands. So I agree with Diogo Sperb, you have started with a bad practice. Ofc. you can run javascript code before the DOM loads, but those should not involve the DOM. You can do for example XHR requests to the server, or use the history API to override the URI, etc... You can even create DOM elements by using document fragments, but you should not render them. As far as I know rendering DOM elements is sync, so you won't have similar problems after the DOM is loaded.

Just to mention, nobody uses `alert()` nowadays, we use `console.log()`, which does not block the page from loading.

Note:
I don't understand why people are downvoting your question. I think it is a good javascript beginner question. I guess haters gonna hate. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of JavaScript in the browser. Different behavior across browsers is to be expected, not an exception.

It should help to know though that what your code does is not recommended. Any JavaScript statement that actually does something (like your alerts) should come only right before closing the body tag.

Bad things happend when you don't respect that and try to run code while the browser is still rendering the page. You can have any amount of declarations before that though, as long as they are not called until the end of the document body.

Comment: Diogo, this is an example from a basic javascript book; but here by spreading out the script elements between the html, i am trying to see that the javascript interpreter will pass it in serial order rendering html and stopping at next script and executing it before going forward.

Comment: I see. Please note that browser rendering is not expected to wait for the completion of every JavaScript statement. But the JavaScript interpreter will execute the code in proper sequence, i.e. you won't see the second alert before the first alert. You could replace the `alert()` call with the non-interactive `console.log()` to ease your testing.